# how to remove top space between input edit text and its content

Tags: android, xml

[image]

there is a little space between text input layout and edit text despite of i have no padding which make the text of edit text not vertically aligned

and here is the xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/first_name_layout"
                style="@style/AppTheme.TextInputStyle_II"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:baselineAligned="true"
                android:clipToPadding="true"
                android:hint="@string/hint_first_name"
                android:textColorHint="@color/hintTextColor"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="32dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="32dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="32dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="32dp"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/darkTextColor"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/last_name_layout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/first_name_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Body2"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkTextColor" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

which make appear like this

[image]

and kareem word isn't vertically aligned

Comment: What is difference between firstname and phone?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a padding with negative value will suit your problem

```
 android:paddingTop="-10dp"
```

Comment: it doesn't help